# Article length validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, blogs, maxlength

I am currently learning Rails and I followed the "Getting started with Rails" tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. My question is how do I validate length of an article and if it is over a certain length append the three dots at the end?

I have a page that shows all the articles with no comments and I have a page that shows each specific article with the comments. If someone wanted to see the rest of the article and the comments they would click a link to see that specific article.

My index.html.erb shows every article but I only want it to show lets say up to 200 words  of each article and append the three dots

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
 <h1><%= article.title %></h1>
  <p><%= article.text %></p>
  <%= link_to 'Show full post', article_path(article) %>

<% end %>
```

show.html.erb shows the full article with the comments

```
    <h1>
      <%= @articles.title %>
    </h1>

    <p>
    <%= @articles.text %>
    </p>

    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <%= render @articles.comments %>

    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

and here is the article controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

def show
    @articles = Article.find(params[:id])

end


def new
    @articles = Article.new
end

def edit
    @articles = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @articles = Article.new(articles_params)

    if @articles.save
        redirect_to @articles
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    @articles = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @articles.update(articles_params)
        redirect_to @articles
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @articles = Article.find(params[:id])
    @articles.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
end

private
    def articles_params
        params.require(:articles).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end


    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <%= render @articles.comments %>

    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shorten your text to a certain amount of characters you could use [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate):

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17)
# => "Once upon a ti..."
```

If you really want to shorten your text to a certain amount of words, you could split your string by spaces, count up to the number of words you want and join those words by spaces:

```
string = "Once upon a time in a world far far away"
string.split(" ").join(0, 5).join(" ")
# => "Once upon a time in"
```

As you can see, you'll still have to add the `...` after that, but you only have to do that when your limit (in my example `5`) is smaller than the number of total words (or when the resulting string doesn't match the original string. When I use `15` (there are only 10 words in my string), you don't need to do that:

```
string = "Once upon a time in a world far far away"
string.split(" ").join(0, 15).join(" ")
# => "Once upon a time in a world far far away"
```

To apply this to your code, simply replace `string` with `article.text`. Also, if you're going to use the latter, I would personally create a helper method for it.

Comment: Beautiful... truncate was what I was looking for as I only needed to add it to one line of code. No method needed.. `<%= truncate(article.text, length: 500) %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a validation to model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text, length: { maximum: 1000 }
end
```

For more information, check out [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used the word validation as I didn't need an error message generated. But I can actually use this to help my user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in your view.

```
article.text = "Some article text which should be shown if the length is less than 200, or else it should be truncated"
<% article_array = article.split(" ") %>
<% if article_array.length > 200 %>
    <%= article_array[0..200].join(" ") %>
    <%= link_to "... more", article_path(article) %>
<% else %>
    <%= article.text %>
<% end %>
```